# Where should i store oauth access token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on creating an application , where i am authenticating the user using a third party oauth provider.

i am getting access token and token secret from the provider.

Now i need those access tokenans token secret with every api call. so where should i store that in my express app. Should i store in session or should i do something else .

I am currently storing in session but read it is volunerable to csrf.

Trying to know what is the best way to do it.

Comment: You're making this calls from BE or FE?

Comment: Api call to third party from backend when i receive a request from FE. Like gettasks api call from front end  will now call backend which inturn use the access token and secret ( dudferent for different user ) to call third party api .

Comment: In oauth, you will have a clientID and secrete. Hit a particular WS to get a token and use it for rest of your job. Thats what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

These tokens should be stored in the Users table/collection in the database. That way you can easily fetch them from the Users database table before every API call.

Comment: These are not constants the access token and toke secret will be different for each user . Think if it like you loging through my app using facebook oauth and i retrieve your recent posts using your oauth token.

Comment: This's not correct, `dotenv` you should only store variables on building time, he's going to receive the token and the token secret from a Provider He needs store the information on real time.

Comment: Sorry, the question is written in a very confusing way. Just trying to help but apparently I misunderstood the question. These tokens should be stored in the Users table/collection in the database. I have just updated my provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, all depends of what you're able to do.

**The Secret**
Store the secret on a DB, (Redis, Mongo, SQL, etc).
Here you will be sure that's more secure, also you will be able to consume from any of your server, not just the one who generate it.

**The token**
You can pass it as a header to your FE, and then stored on a cookie, local storage or session storage, then pass it to your BE with each petition, take it and use it to call to your Provider.

This is my approach, maybe is not the only one, but for me is the most secure.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This question does not answer "where" he should store it. It is a given he will store it in a database of some sort, but he gave an example of storing in SessionStorage (database table) and was questioning whether it should be stored here or some other location in the database.

Comment: He's just asking for recommendations of where store his token and his secret, Any answer is really correct, but he should try to understand which one fits better.